# Non-existence Tracial states

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

We know that every non-zero finite dimensional C*-algebra has a tracial state. I am searching for an example of a simple C* algebra without tracial state with explaination. I think you have to look to the calkin algebra on a separable Hilbert space. Someone an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Kind of relevant: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-12/S0002-9939-00-05605-7/S0002-9939-00-05605-7.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Consider the Cuntz algebra $\mathcal O_2$. This is a simple, purely infinite C*-algebra. This means that there exist pairwise orthogonal projections $p,q\in\mathcal O_2$ with $1\sim p\sim q$. Now suppose that $f$ is a tracial state on $\mathcal O_2$.

Then 
$$
1=f(1)=f(p)=f(q).
$$
So 
$$
0\leq f(1-(p+q))=f(1)-f(p)-f(q)=-1,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Besides $K(H)$,do there exist other non-unital simple $C^*$ algebra which have no tracial states?

Comment: I cannot immediately think of an example, but you can always construct things like $K(H)\otimes \mathcal O_2$.

Comment: tensor product of simple $C^*$ algebras is also simple?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the direct sum.

Comment: Does this algebra admit a non degenerate state ?

Comment: If you mean faithful then yes, every separable C$^*$-algebra admits a faithful state.