# There is no trace on Cuntz algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, trace

Here is a general explanation why purely infinite $C^*$-algebras admit no tracial states: [Non-existence Tracial states](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812961/non-existence-tracial-states).

Is my following explanation for non existence of trace on Cuntz algebra $O_n$ (for any $n$) is also correct?

$O_n$ is simple, so if there exisrs a trace $\tau$ then it is faithful (as $\{x|\tau(x^*x)=0\}$ is a two-sided ideal if $\tau$ is a trace). Take one of the partial isometries generate $O_n$, then $\tau(1)=\tau(s^∗s)=\tau(ss^∗)$ but $1−ss^∗$ is positive and satisfies $\tau(1−ss^∗)=0$. Thus, by faithfulness of $\tau$ we get $ss^∗=1$ which is a contradiction for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: I am not an expert at Cuntz algebras but to me this looks correct. If you assume that $\tau \neq 0$ you get a contradiction. So you prove that $\tau = 0$ is the only trace for $n \geq 2$ on the Cuntz algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's a very natural argument. Simpler and nicer than the one I gave on [the answer you quoted](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/813058/22857).